# How to use variable inside %w{}

Tags: ruby

I want to use variable insite %w{} but this is generating only string.

I have try with

```
a="hello",
b="world"
%w{a b}
```

But this is display  `["a", "b"]` I want to display ["hello","world"]

Comment: Have you tried `[a, b]`, because `%w{all strings}` creates a string array

Comment: I know [a, b] will work but i want to use %w{all strings}

Comment: `irb(main):017:0> %W(#{a} #{b}) => ["hello", "world"]`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to use variables you can use interpolation and the `%W` variant

```
a = "hello"
b = "world"

pp %W{#{a} #{b} this is normal text} #=> ["hello", "world", "this", "is", "normal", "text"]
```

Comment: As of version 2.6, the result of `%w{#{x}}`, as well as any combination of quotes, extra text, parens instead of brackets, etc. that I can think of (where `x = 'a b c') always results in `["\#{x}"]` for me. This may have worked back in 2013, but unless I'm missing something stupid (entirely possible), the interpolation syntax is now escaped and taken as a literal.