# Using variables with %w or %W - Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, variables

I have a similar issue as this post:
    [How to use variable inside %w{}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707709/how-to-use-variable-inside-w/41924187#41924187)
but my issue is a bit different. I want to take a string variable and convert it to an array using %w or %W.

```
text = gets.chomp   # get user text string
```

#e.g I enter "first in first out"

```
words = %w[#{text}]  # convert text into array of strings

puts words.length
puts words
```

## Console output

```
1
first in first out
```

Keeps the text as a block of string and doesn't split it into an array words ["first","in", "first", "out"]

```
words = text.split (" ")   # This works fine

words = %w[#{gets.chomp}]  # This doesn't work either
words = %w['#{gets.chomp}'] # This doesn't work either
words = %W["#{gets.chomp}"] # This doesn't work either
words = %w("#{gets.chomp}") # This doesn't work either
```

Comment: although it's not idiomatic, you could use `%w{#{gets.chomp}}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%w` is not intended to do any splitting, it's a way of expressing that the following string *in the source* should be split. In essence it's just a short-hand notation.

In the case of `%W` the `#{...}` chunks are treated as a single token, any spaces contained within are considered an integral part.

The correct thing to do is this:

```
words = text.trim.split(/\s+/)
```

Doing things like `%W[#{...}]` is just as pointless as `"#{...}"`. If you need something cast as a string, call `.to_s`. If you need something split call `split`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  However, it would be rare to get have a situation where a string is hard coded
    words = %w("first in first out")
most of the time one would get string variables or input from a user

I thought it would be a nifty way to use the %w

thanks again.

Comment: @Nakovskii I'm not sure what you mean. If you need some other information, let me know, I'll add as necessary. Otherwise accept the answer if it solved your problem.